# Choosing a pump to inject liquid into a pressurised water pipe

Tags: fluid

I'm interested in using a pump to inject liquid into a mains water pipe (3-6 bar pressure)

I don't know what pump to use as they all seem too big for the task they are carrying out. I want to use a variable speed 12V/24V pump that only needs to inject a max of 2L per hour but is this going to be too small to deal with injecting into a pressurised pipe?

Could somebody show me an example of the smallest pump you could use for this?

Comment: A pump that can exceed the 6 bar pressure...

Comment: A category of pumps that is just right is corrosion inhibitor pumps. There are a great number of these pumps in service injecting small amounts into high pressure oil and gas lines. Some run continuously ,some intermittent some on battery power. I don't know brands but inhibitor companies like Nalco may have info.

Answer (score 1):

IMO, the wide range of pressures you are talking about rules out a centrifugal pump. 2l/h is really little flow. I would look for a membrane pump, maybe even a dosing pump (here: a membrane pump with variable stroke) as these are often available or adjustable for small volume flow.

Using these search terms ("membrane dosing pump 2l/h 6 bar") I found [this by Sera](https://www.sera-web.com/pdf/dosierpumpen/magnetmembranpumpen/produktinformationen/pi-2001_01_magnetmembranpumpen_204_1__en.pdf). So *something* is available, depending on your project maybe not within your budget.

AFAIK, peristaltic pumps are seldom rated for 6bar but I could be wrong and a search in this direction might yield a cheaper solution.

Comment: Thanks Mart. My issue with dosing/membrane pumps is their size. I might be able to control pressure down to 2-3 bar if i found the right peristaltic pump. The liquid is organic acid so would this have a damaging effect on a peristaltic pump?

Comment: Talk to a supplier, an acid resistant pump should be available. When the mains pressure is 3-6 bar, why regulate down to 2-3 bar?